# Video editing software to cut out sections without re-encoding

Tags: video-editing

So currently I use `AVIDemux` which allows me to set a start point and end point on I-frames and save it to a MP4/MKV file without having to re-encode it. The problem is I want to take multiple sections of the video and save it as one file.

For example let's say I have a video that is 60 minutes long. I want to take the 5m to 10m section, and also the 23m to 47m section and save that all into 1 file without re-encoding. Another simple example is I have a move I recorded from TV and want to cut out the commercials from it. And since I want no quality loss I would have to cut on I-frames which is fine with me.

I can't use `ffmpeg` because I have to visually inspect which sections to keep and which ones to discard. I looking for a freeware solution but if there is a commercial one that is fine. Also prefer a Windows app over a Linux app.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/84836/82185)