# Cut several pairs of start and end time from a video at once

Tags: video-editing

I have a one-hour video. I scanned it and figured out I needed to remove the parts which lie between the times: 00:00 to 2:19,
3:28 to 5:42,
9:35 to 9:45,
15:14 to 15:48,
20:23 to 21:50,
30:40 to 30:54,
33:55 to 35:05,
47:40 to 47:55

The online software I found could trim video from a start time to an end time. Is there any tool I could provide all these sets of times, remove those parts from the video, and return me the resulting video?
As of now, I am doing something like this could be extremely tedious. The only way I could think is, given any removal start and end time, to trim the video from 00 to start and end-time to end of the video and merge these two. So the resulting will have the given part removed. But with multiple start and end times, this becomes too tedious.
Not sure if `ffmpeg` has any such option.

Comment: You should add information for which OS you need the software. Also should it be only freeware, or are comercial solutions OK?

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html) is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs. Tasks can be automated using projects, job queue and powerful scripting capabilities.

Avidemux is available for Linux, BSD, Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows under the GNU GPL license. The program was written from scratch by Mean, but code from other people and projects has been used as well. Patches, translations and even bug reports are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can certainly do this.

See this previous answer to help to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594412/cut-multiple-parts-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score -1):

Introducing Videocut on this site. It is is supposed to cut (fast) a video (no linear editor), using either the integrated muxer or ffmpeg.

[image]

Check out my [documentation](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) and how to install it on your Linux system. Videocut might work on windows, but was not tested for it.

Due to corresponding comments I'd like to point out that **I am** the author of this free software.

Comment: Pleas disclose affiliation more clearly, thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing it out to me - Obviously I didn't know.